# MySQL Group By not producing expected result

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure:

```
rec_id  product_id  quantity  quantity_in  quantity_out  balance  stock_date  status

   1      2          342          NULL           17        325    2009-10-23     1
   2      2          325          NULL          124        201    2009-10-23     1
   3      1          156          NULL           45        111    2009-10-23     1
   4      2          201          NULL          200          1    2009-10-23     1
   5      2            1          NULL            1          0    2009-10-23     1
   6      1          111          NULL           35         76    2009-10-23     1
```

All I want is the last transaction done for a given product: `product_id`, `quantity`, `quantity_out` and `balance` from this table.

Example, there are 2 transaction done for product 2 (ids 1 & 2):
final balance for `product_id` 2 is 0 -> stored in rec_id 5
final balance for `product_id` 1 is 76 -> stored in rec_id 6

Final result/output should be like this:

```
recid  productid  quantity  quantityin  quantityout  balance  stock_date  status
  5         2         1       NULL            1         0     2009-10-23    1
  6         1       111       NULL           35        76     2009-10-23    1
```

Comment: Please be more clear about your expected result...show it as a table result

Comment: want recent records group by product_id, so that i get only one record of product.

Comment: In the above 6 record, for product_id '1', the recent record is rec_id 5 and for product_id '2', the recent record is rec_id 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/sql-retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest record for each product like:

```
select max(rec_id) as MaxRec
from YourTable
group by product_id
```

Using a subquery, you can retrieve the latest rows for their product:

```
select *
from YourTable
where rec_id in (
    select max(rec_id) as MaxRec
    from YourTable
    group by product_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single query with no subqueries:

```
SELECT main.*
FROM YourTable main
LEFT JOIN YourTable newer
    ON newer.product_id = main.product_id AND newer.rec_id > main.rec_id
WHERE newer.rec_id IS NULL;
```

You can tweak the field list however you want--make sure you select fields from main, not newer, which should be all null.